# Controlling the 'alpha' level in a ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

In ggplot2, how can I make the legend have a semi-transparent background.

The following code, gives a fully transparent background (and positioning control)

```
plot <- plot + theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1),
                       legend.direction="vertical",
                       legend.box="horizontal",
                       legend.box.just = c("top"), 
                       legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"))
```

But how can one control the level of alpha, I don't believe that `element_rect` has that ability.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can control semitransparency with function `alpha()` from package `scales` by providing color and alpha value. This function can be used inside `element_rect()` when you provide color for `fill=`.

```
library(scales)    
p<-ggplot(iris,aes(Petal.Length,Petal.Width,color=Species))+geom_point()
p+theme(legend.position=c(1,1),legend.justification=c(1,1),
        legend.direction="vertical",
        legend.box="horizontal",
        legend.box.just = c("top"), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill=alpha('blue', 0.4)))
```

[image]

Comment: I tried that, but my ggplot2 reports error "Cannot find the function alpha"...??? Using the latest version, 0.9.3.1

Comment: This function is in library(scales). Updated my answer.