# ggplot2 make legend key fill transparent

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am trying to make the legend key fill for a ggplot transparent.  I followed the instructions on one of Hadley's ggplot2 guides for changing the legend key fill, but for some reason when I set the fill to transparent it fills with gray.  Even when I set the legend key fill to white, it still appears gray in the final plot.

Here is an example:

```
library(ggplot2)

data1 = c(0,10, 11, 23, 33, 40, 41, 50, 59, 68, 76, 88, 90, 99)
data2 = c(2, 8, 10, 22, 39, 47, 49, 55, 62, 70, 76, 86, 88, 95)

df = data.frame(data1, data2)

(plot = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(data1, data2,colour="sample1"))+
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1,linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="data2", x="data1", 
       title="sample 1 data1 vs data2") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "white"),
        legend.justification = c(1,0), legend.position = c(1,0))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Sample") )
```

[image: Example_plot]

If I set `theme(legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "red"))` I get the following plot:
[image: red_fill]

So it appears that I can change the legend key fill, but just not to the color white or transparent.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong, or if there is just no way to make the legend key fill transparent/white ?

**EDIT: Setting `theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0.0)))` Does not fix the problem.**

**See here:**

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

data1 = c(0,10, 11, 23, 33, 40, 41, 50, 59, 68, 76, 88, 90, 99)
data2 = c(2, 8, 10, 22, 39, 47, 49, 55, 62, 70, 76, 86, 88, 95)

df = data.frame(data1, data2)

(plot = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(data1, data2,colour="sample1"))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="data2", x="data1", 
       title="sample 1 data1 vs data2") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = alpha("red", 0)),
        legend.justification = c(1,0), legend.position = c(1,0))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Sample") )
```

**EDIT2:  If I use `geom_line()` instead of `geom_smooth` I am able to set the legend key fill to NA, so it must be because the line in `geom_smooth` has a gray area for the confidence interval around it, therefore the legend key mirrors that look.**

```
(plot = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(data1, data2,colour="sample1"))+
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1,linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="data2", x="data1", 
       title="sample 1 data1 vs data2") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = NA, fill = NA),
        legend.justification = c(1,0), legend.position = c(1,0))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Sample") )
```

[image: geom_line]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controlling the 'alpha' level in a ggplot2 legend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251966/controlling-the-alpha-level-in-a-ggplot2-legend)

Comment: setting `legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA)` gave the same result as before.  the key fill is still gray.

Comment: @VermillionAzure In my edit I explained why the solution in the link you provided does not work in this scenario.

Comment: if you add se = FALSE to your geom_smooth() expression your code works.  so what you see in your legend it's the confidence band

Comment: I just realized that myself.  I realized that if I use geom_line() instead of geom_smooth() then I am able to set the fill to NA.  I suppose I can live with not having the confidence band, but its too bad I can't have both!  Thanks for your insight.  EDIT: Ahh but using geom_line() will not work on my actual data set, because it is not smoothed, so I will use your solution to set se=FALSE instead

Comment: @Reilstein I'm going to guess that the background to the fill is tethered to that of the confidence band. If there were more than one line that might make sense. Just my guess.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could trick it if you want. Add a second `geom_smooth()`. The first with a confidence band and you don't show the legend. With the second one you remove the band but show the legend.

```
df$Color <- "Red"
df1 <- df
(plot = ggplot() +
  geom_smooth(data=df, aes(data1, data2,colour=Color), se = TRUE, show.legend = FALSE) + 
  geom_smooth(data=df1, aes(data1, data2,colour=Color), se=FALSE) +
  geom_abline(intercept=0, slope=1,linetype="dashed", color = "black")+
  scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits=c(0,100))+
  theme_classic()+
  labs(y="data2", x="data1", 
       title="sample 1 data1 vs data2") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold"),
        legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "white"),
        legend.justification = c(1,0), legend.position = c(1,0))+
  scale_color_discrete(name="Sample"))
```

[image]

Comment: This solution isn't working for me.  Have you tried it?

Comment: Ah I got it to work by removing the mapping for the geom_smooth() with se=TRUE.  So if I use `geom_smooth(data=df, aes(data1, data2), se=TRUE) + geom_smooth(data=df1, aes(data1,data2, colour="Sample1"), se=FALSE)` then it works

Comment: I just added a line missing to my code, sorry about that. I tested a few things before getting this answer

Comment: This solution works. In my case, I was also able to do this:


`legend.key = element_rect(colour = "transparent", fill = "transparent")`

Answer (score 26):

I was going crazy with this behavior as well, so here is a working solution for your example:

```
plot + guides(color=guide_legend(override.aes=list(fill=NA)))
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21066077/remove-fill-around-legend-key-in-ggplot) thread for more information.

Comment: Can you give more details about why that is a working solution?

Comment: If I understand correctly, geom_smooth uses `fill` to draw the band when se=TRUE is set. As its names implies, `override.aes` overrides this aesthetic for the generated legend, hence the `fill` of geom_smooth is no longer drawn for the legend while all other settings remain at default.

Answer (score 16):

Additionally to `legend.key = element_blank()` you can put
`legend.background=element_blank()` within `theme()`, to make the text transparent as well

This will also make the default white background transparent when using `gg_themes`

Answer (score 11):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40375246/6688930) seems to be the simplest solution, setting `legend.key = element_blank()` in the `theme()` definition.

Comment: didn't work for me. Did you test it with `geom_smooth`?

Answer (score 10):

To make use of the transparency levels, one can use:

For the entire legend:

```
theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0.5)))
```

`alpha("white", 0)` being completely transparent like `element_blank()`,
and `alpha("white", 1)` having no transparency.

Now, for the key - if key and background have different transparencies:

```
theme(legend.background=element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0)),
      legend.key=element_rect(fill = alpha("white", .5)))
```

Note: background transparency overrules the one for the key, i.e. background alpha must be smaller than key alpha.