# ggplot2 transparent/white legend key with stat_ellipse

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, background, legend

I've got a plot where I'm using `stat_ellipse` to show 95% confidence ellipses around some points. I'd like to get rid of the grey background behind the points in the legend, but it's just not working. I am aware of other similar posts (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35108443/ggplot2-make-legend-key-fill-transparent)), but this seems to be its own thing (given I can't set `se=FALSE` for `stat_ellipse`). Is there another way or am I out of luck?

See my example code below:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length,fill=Species)) + 
  stat_ellipse(geom="polygon",level=0.95,alpha=0.1) +
  geom_point(color="black",shape=21,size=5) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank()) # + 
  # this also doesn't work:
  # theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill="white"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was simple: it was just a matter of adding `show.legend=FALSE` to the stat_ellipse call:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris,aes(x=Sepal.Length,y=Petal.Length,fill=Species)) + 
  stat_ellipse(geom="polygon",level=0.95,alpha=0.1,show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(color="black",shape=21,size=5) +
  theme(legend.key = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: You could also move `aes(fill = Species)` out of `ggplot()` (which applies it to every geom) and into `geom_point()`, then add `aes(group = Species)` to `stat_ellipse`. But that would result in a grey ellipse for every Species, which is perhaps not what you want.