# Customize ggmap() legend background

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap, tmap

In the code below, is it possible to make the legend background semi-transparent? I cannot pass an`alpha`value to`element_rect()`in`legend.background`or`legend.box.background`to do this. As an example,`tm_layout()`in`tmap`package can do this with arguments`legend.bg.color = "white"`and`legend.bg.alpha = 0.5`.

```
suppressMessages(library(ggmap))
data(crime)
houston.map <- get_map(location = geocode("Houston"),
                       zoom = 14,
                       maptype = "satellite")
ggmap(houston.map, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") +
  geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, color = offense), data = crime) +
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill = alpha("white", 0.7)),
        legend.key = element_rect(color = NA, fill = NA))
```

**Update:** Thanks to jazzurro I updated the code to pass`alpha()`in`element_rect(),`and the attached picture is how it looks. This answers my question.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16251966/controlling-the-alpha-level-in-a-ggplot2-legend) before?

Comment: @jazzurro That's quick! No I did not see it before, thanks for pointing this out. Let me check it out.

Comment: I hope the question helps you!

Comment: @jazzurro It helped indeed. I updated the post, and now need to fiddle around to make the legend keys more visible.

Comment: your post is not reproducible and not clear if you still need help or not

Comment: @MLavoie The post is not reproducible because of my updated code. The answer came from jazzuro's comment (as noted in the update), but I did not know how to accept a comment as an answer. I have now edited my update to this effect. Thanks for pointing this out.